# How to download files continuously using Python wget or urllib3

Tags: python, wget, urllib3

How to download files continuously using Python wget or urllib3.

My wish is to download automatic files at intervals, such as at intervals of 1 hour. on the official urllib3 page, there is Retrying Requests content for its users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me give you an answer and you can clarify the question:

```
 from time import sleep

 while True:
    download()
    sleep(36000)
```

where download() is a function that calls wget or urllib3.